# PowerShell script problem

Tags: c#, powershell

Here is the code:

```
static String checkBackUp()
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    runspace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();                     
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Get-WBSummary");
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
    try
    {
        results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
    }

    runspace.Close();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that this runs every cmdlet (like `Get-Process` for example) but when I try to verify if a backup has been made (`Get-WBSummary`), it spits out the following error:

> The term 'Get-WBSummary' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

However when I put the command straight into PowerShell, it executes the command.  I have already tried to add a SnapIn but this did not work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-WBSummary` isn't a regular built-in Powershell cmdlet. You'll need to do

`Add-PSSnapin Windows.ServerBackup`

at some point in your code after the runspace is initialised.

Comment: Like i said in my question i did :) and it didnt help. i had it like this :

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Add-Pssnapin"     Windows.serverbackup");
            Command addSnapin = new Command("Add-PSSnapin");
            addSnapin.Parameters.Add("Name", "Windows.serverbackup");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(addSnapin);

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an initial session state and add the snapin. Here is how to do it

```
initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] {"Path\to\module\here"});
```